# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to call a JavaScript function after asp:UpdatePanel. The following solution works fine for IE 8 and above, but throws exception for IE 7.

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

                prm.add_endRequest(function () {
                    DoJobOne();
                    DoJobTwo();
                });
```

Exception: **Unable to get property 'PageRequestManager' of undefined or null reference**

I tried adding the App_browser from NuGet. Still the problem exists. Any work around to load javascript post UpdatePanel?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, might be helpful for others.

```
    $(function () {
       DoJobOne();
       DoJObTwo();
   });

   function pageLoad(sender, args) {
       if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
           DoJobOne();
           DoJObTwo();
       }

   }
```